# JNI Deleted Accidentally

Tags: java

I am using Ubuntu 10.04. I've accidentally deleted the `jni` folder in `/usr/lib/` by using the root terminal.

Is there any way that I can reinstall these files?, or should I reload Ubuntu?. I've tried copying files from another laptop (same make ,Configuration as mine) but 2 files were not being copied.

Answer (score 1):

The files in `/usr/lib/jni` were all installed by various Ubuntu packages and they can be restored by reinstalling those packages. You can reinstall a package with a command like:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall <packagename>
```

where `<packagename>` is the name of the package you want to reinstall.

Figuring out which packages you need to reinstall might be a little tricky, because it looks like multiple packages install files in `/usr/lib/jni`. You can probably get a rough idea of the packages to reinstall with this command:

```
dpkg -l | grep jni
```

That will list the packages you have installed with `jni` in their names. I would start by reinstalling each of those packages and see if it fixes your problem.

Comment: actually i deleted the folder name JNI from the /usr/lib

Comment: Reinstalling the package that is related to it will repair the folder structure, as it unpacks all the files from the initial .deb installer (which should contain the folder you deleted)

Comment: Yes, you need to reinstall the packages that originally installed the files in /usr/lib/jni that you deleted. I'll edit my answer to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Find the `JNI` package name then run this command in terminal:

`apt-get --reinstall install PACKAGE_NAME`